# Android 4.4 Chrome - Text cutting off

Tags: android, google-chrome, soundcloud

Hi on this site http://www.saraswati.co.uk

I embedded a Soundcloud player on the homepage, however since then on my Sony Z2, the text on the home page is randomly cutting off. It is fine on iOS, and desktop browsers.

I have researched and can't find an obvious fix also informing Soundcloud developers, they still haven't got back to me.

Is this a bug with Chrome, there were no problems prior the Soundcloud embed, but there are only problems that I have seen on Chrome Android 4.4.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm researching this and there has been rendering issues with Google Fonts, but I have tested that the problem still exists with or without the Google Font.

Comment: OK I've reorganised the site, eliminating this problem, but not solving it. Can close.